# Oracle PL/SQL Triggers

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Why can't we perform Commits in PL/SQL triggers? If triggers are auto commit why do we need PRAGMA autonomous transactions to be used for commit ?Please explain .. I am very confused about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are entities that are invoked automatically, hence normally the usage of a commit or a rollback is not recommended in triggers.  But there are certain situations in which we have to use commit or rollback in triggers. For this we use `PRAGMA` autonomous transactions.

Once started, an autonomous transaction is fully independent. It shares no locks, resources, or commit-dependencies with the main transaction. You can log events, increment retry counters, and so on, even if the main transaction rolls back.

For example, there is a set of transactions `t1` and `t2`. The whole point of transactions is to ensure that a set of changes is atomic and is either completely successful or completely rejected. If I update a row in `t1` but my transaction rolls back. And `t2` changes have already been made and committed so they don't roll back. That generally means that the `t2` data is now incorrect. Allowing code to be partially successful is almost never a good idea.

Example code how `PRAGMA` can be used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytrg
AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE    
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;    
BEGIN    
   myschema.myproc(:new.ID, :new.NAME, :new.TYPE_CODE, :new.LANGUAGE);    
   COMMIT;    
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A point of clarification: triggers are **not** auto commit; they commit or roll back when the transaction that triggered them commits or rolls back.